# Вставляет значения по всем ключам, вместо заданного

Tags: python, словари, dict

Есть словарь `fioMap` следующей структуры:

```
фио:  
   день1:  
        номер_заявки1: значение  
        номер_заявки2: значение  
        номер_заявки3: значение  
  ....
```

**Вид словаря до заполнения:**

```
{  
  'Иванов Иван Иванович': {  
         '2021-05-01': {},   
         '2021-05-02': {},  
              ....  
         '2021-05-31': {}  
  },  
  'Петров Петр Петрович': {  
         '2021-05-01': {},   
         '2021-05-02': {},  
              ....  
         '2021-05-31': {}  
  },   
  'Александров Александр Александрович':  
              ......  
}
```

**Выполнив следующий код:**
`fioMap['Иванов Иван Иванович']['2021-05-01']['number113'] = 7`

У меня заполняется первый день у **ВСЕХ** людей до конца словоря. Хотя я хочу что бы он заполнился только у *Иванов Иван Иванович*.

**Вид словаря после заполнения:**

```
{  
  'Иванов Иван Иванович': {  
         '2021-05-01': { 'number113': 7},   
         '2021-05-02': {},  
             ....  
         '2021-05-31': {}  
  },  
  'Петров Петр Петрович': {  
         '2021-05-01': { 'number113': 7 },    
         '2021-05-02': {},  
             ....  
         '2021-05-31': {}  
  },   
  'Александров Александр Александрович':  
         '2021-05-01': { 'number113': 7 }, 
            ......  
}
```

Причем, следующий код: `print(fioMap['Бородин Сергей Александрович']['2021-05-01'])`
Выведет только одно значнение : `{ 'number113': 7}`

Почему у меня заполняются все дни, если я изначально указываю, что хочу заполнить день у **конкретного** *фио*?
Как сделать так что бы заполнялся только конкретное *фио*?

### upd:

У меня словарь генерируется следующим образом:

```
fioMap = {}
for id in workerViewMap:
    #print(workerViewMap[id])
    fioMap[workerViewMap[id].get('worker_fio')] = {}
```

На этом этапе fioMap имеет вид
фио: {}

Далее я генерирую словарь с датами:

```
dayMap = {}
for id in workerViewMap:
    day = workerViewMap[id].get('work_day')
    dayMap[day] = {}
```

Словарь dayMap выглядит как:
день1: {}

Причем дней всегда 31(ну или 30, короче сколько в месяце - столько и дней)

```
for id in workerViewMap:
    fio = workerViewMap[id].get('worker_fio')
    fioMap[fio] = dayMap
```

Вот здесь я обращаюсь к fioMap по ключу(фамилии) и присваиваю ему dayMap

В итоге получается словарь такого вида, который я показал выше.

Может ли быть такое, что у меня все ФИО в fioMap на самом деле ссылаются на один словарь dayMap.
И Именно поэтому при изменении у одного - изменяет у всех.
Если это так, то как сделать так, что бы у каждого фио был свой dayMap.

---

Подскажите тогда как правильно заполнять вложенные словари?

Comment: Не может быть. Что-то упускаете или недоговариваете. fioMap['Иванов Иван Иванович']['2021-05-01']['number113'] = 7 однозначно должна внести изменения только для ивана ивановича.

Comment: Блин, что так сложно комментарии писать. У меня есть одно предположение почему такое происходит и связанно оно с тем каким образом я генерирую словарь. Весь этап генирации я описал здесь: https://pastebin.com/ea90tUes
Проблема как я понял в том, что все мои ФИО ссылаются на ОДИН и тот же словарь dayMap. 
Подскажите тогда как правильно нужно генерировать вложенные словари??

Comment: Да, думаю так и есть. Можешь проверить посмотрев id словарей  - id(тут нужный dayMap) для разных ФИО. Если id совпадают, значит они ссылаются на один и тот же словарь.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была именно в том, что все значения по ключам(фио)
Ссылались на один и тот же объект dayMap.

Изменив генерацию словаря таким образом, что у меня для каждого фио создается новый dayMap ошибка исчезла.

```
for fio in fioMap:
    dayMap = {}
    for id in workerViewMap:
        day = workerViewMap[id].get('work_day')
        dayMap[day] = {}
    fioMap[fio] = dayMap
```

Теперь все заполняется красиво и легко.
Но все-таки можно ли где-нибудь почитать о том, как грамотно заполнять вложенные словари, да и словари в целом.